# Jackson configure own json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I start playing around with the Jackson json but i stuck at some point. I get that Json returned:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Group99",
                "students": [
                    {
                        "studentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "studentId": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "studentId": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "schoolId": 10
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Group100",
                "students": [
                    {
                        "studentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "studentId": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "studentId": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "schoolId": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to get a JSON without the student array in it. Like so

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Group99",
                "schoolId": 10
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Group100",
                "schoolId": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Right now i get a list out of the database and i created an ObjectMapper which just return ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(list). How can I modify the list so that the student array is excluded in the JSON with Jackson?

EDIT JAVA CODE

The Java code which i have right now is

```
List<Assessment> assessments = (List<Assessment>)   assessmentRepository.findGroupsByUsernameAndAssessmentId(username, assessmentId);
    //2. Convert JSON to Java object
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // create the new JSON
    List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= assessments.size() - 1; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < assessments.get(i).getGroups().length; k++){
            // create the String with only the wanted information
        }
    }
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(groups);
```

I am not sure if that is the right way and i would expect that there is an easier way

UPDATE 
I fixed it with using a HashMap. Java code is to find below. Let me know guys if that is a good way or if there are better one

```
Assessment assessment = (Assessment) assessmentRepository.findGroupsByUsernameAndAssessmentId(username, assessmentId);
    // 2. Convert JSON to Java object
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // create the new JSON
    ArrayList<Object> jsonWithoutTeacherAndStudents = new ArrayList<Object>();
    HashMap<String, String> jsonKeyAndValueMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    GroupSummary[] summary = assessment.getGroups();
    for (int i = 0; i < assessment.getGroups().length; i++) {
        jsonKeyAndValueMap.put("id", summary[i].getId());
        jsonKeyAndValueMap.put("name", summary[i].getName());
        jsonKeyAndValueMap.put("schoolId", Integer.toString(summary[i].getSchoolId()));
        jsonWithoutTeacherAndStudents.add(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonKeyAndValueMap));
    }
    return jsonWithoutTeacherAndStudents.toString();
```

Comment: Note: you really should include Java class definitions, not just JSON -- data-binding is art of converting from one to the other and back; so just JSON isn't enough to answer most questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jackson attributes to set a @JsonIgnore for the list you don't want to show up in your POJO class.

Edit:/
If that is to strict for you, you also can write a [JsonFilter](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) for the Object Mapper. In your case the [SimpleBeanPropertyFilter](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) should work just fine as factory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but i want to return the properties in another json  so the @JsonIgnore annotation is not the best fit.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i needed :) it is just working perfect